# Unexpected result from round(), bug or feature?

Tags: php, math

php returns "-0" on

```
round(-0.2,0));
```

Same for

```
round(-10,-2);
```

I can't see how this makes sense, but I welcome any ideas before filing a bug.

Comment: This is standard IEEE 754 behaviour (at least for rounding to integral). So almost certainly feature, not bug.

Comment: ... though it has to be said, the standard doesn't spell this out particularly clearly. Section 5.9 of IEEE 754-2008 (which defines the various `roundToIntegral*` functions) simply says that "The rounding is analogous to that specified in Clause 4, ...". Section 4.3 then says: "Inexact numeric floating-point results always have the same sign as the unrounded result." Together with "These operations convert zero operands to zero results of the same sign" from section 5.9 again, that just about covers all the cases.

Comment: @MarkDickinson it totally must be an answer.

Comment: Ok, you won me over: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero